# For DynamoDB and node should I use data mapper?

Tags: node.js, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am making a web app using node and dynamodb. For sql database there is Sequelize and for mongodb there is mongoose. But for dynamodb, what should I use? Should I use [dynamodb data mapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb)? Are there any other alternative for dyanmodb?

Comment: You mean which ODM is appropriate to dynamodb using node.js?

Comment: If you are looking for a more feature complete solution, take a look at https://github.com/shiftcode/dynamo-easy which just got a major release with lots of features.
Also supports the new transaction feature and nested attribute updates with a simple to use fluent api for all requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not using the one AWS has made ? [DynamoDB Data mapper](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-data-mapper-js). Its a typescript project so it comes with types as well. I dont know the difference with this and the one you picked. Speaking for mine, it's a good choice for many applications. If your attributes are of types string,int,datetime... then it would help you. But I couldn't use it with nested types. If you a 'map' attribute and it has some mutable nested attributes the mapper cannot handle that. There is only just update item functionality.

In short,

- If you are going with a schemeless model unlike SQL where you attributes vary for each entry
- If you are doing an attribute specific operations like only updating a field of map instead of the entire map attribute (because UpdateItem updates all the nested fields)

Then I wouldn't suggest using mappers. Instead, like me, for such projects you can create small dynamodb modules (like clients) that handles all the DocumentClient operations. Document client becomes so natural and easy to use a while after you get used to it.